# How to connect plaid with stripe in sandbox mode

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid

I'm trying to connect Plaid with Stripe for some tests and investigation (stripe ACH). Does plaid provide this possibility for using in sandbox, and without real data? Problems in the bank account, as I understand for connection is necessary to provide real bank account, but I don't have this one. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From the [Plaid docs](https://plaid.com/docs/auth/partnerships/stripe/#test-with-sandbox-credentials):

"Plaid's Sandbox API environment is compatible with Stripe's "test mode" API. To test the integration in Sandbox mode, simply use the Plaid Sandbox credentials when launching Link with a `link_token` created in the Sandbox environment. The Stripe bank account token created in the Sandbox environment will always match the Stripe bank test account with account number 000123456789 and routing number 110000000, and with the Stripe account that is linked in the Plaid developer dashboard.

Use Stripe's ACH API in test mode to create test transfers using the bank account tokens you retrieve from Plaid's Sandbox API environment."

Comment: Yeh, I should work, but I got error like "need to connect stripe to the plaid", and question is about connection using dashboards

Comment: Have you connected your Stripe and Plaid accounts as described in https://plaid.com/docs/auth/partnerships/stripe/#set-up-your-plaid-and-stripe-accounts?

Comment: yep, but it's required to connect real american bank account